# After sending for array is displayed in the page

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have an HTML site on which I have a form. The form is sent with the `method=post` through a php document. Every entry in the form, gets to the mail successfully. Then in that PHP I have a "Thank you" note which also appears. The problem is found on the bottom of the page where an array is displayed. It says: 
`Array ([0] => my text [1] => my text2)`

I obviously don't want it to be there, so what can I do to hide it or how can I fix this?
Here is the picture:
[image: Some strange array display]

Comment: Look for `print_r($someArrayVar)` and remove/comment it.

Comment: can you post some code here

Comment: Thank you for the help, i did had the `print_r($someArrayVar)` hiding in the code.
Thanks everybody.
Special thanks to, Jonathan Kuhn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a `print_r()`

If you are unsure where it is, and if you are using Linux(probably works on Mac, too) -

you can run:

`grep -R "print_r"` in your console to find where it is.